# Как замутить (отключить) звуки идущие из окна, имея его хендл и хендл его процесса?

Tags: c++, winapi, golang

**tldr**: У меня имеется хендл процесса и хендл окна. Надо отключить замутить/выставить на 0 громкость для данного окна.

Появилась необходимость в софт на golang внедрить фичу: "*мут окон при их открытии по пути их выполняемого файла*".
Для этого я сделал `SetWinEventHook` и в обработчике отфильтровал всё по `EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE`, получил путь до исполняемого файла, проверил по регулярке и сейчас мне надо для данного окна вырубить все звуки (как будто мы уменьшаем или мутим громкость в микшере).

```go
func MakeMuteCallback(processPattern *regexp.Regexp) HWINEVENTHOOK {
    return func(handle HANDLE, event DWORD, hwnd HWND, i int32, i2 int32, dword2 DWORD, dword3 DWORD) LRESULT {
        if HWND(event) == EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE {
            if _, processId := GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd); processId != 0 {
                if processHandle, err := windows.OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ, false, processId); err == nil {
                    name := GetModuleFileNameEx(HANDLE(processHandle), 0)
                    if processPattern.MatchString(strings.ToLower(name)) {
                        // MuteALLInWindow(hwnd, processHandle)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return 0
    }
}

func MountMuteHook(callback HWINEVENTHOOK) HHOOK {
    return SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY, 0, callback, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT)
}
```

Данный хук ставится и убирается в определённые моменты работы программы. Логично, когда он работает и открывается окно (у которого исполняемый файл подходит по регулярке) его надо замУтить (и только его, ибо отловленная программа могла создать окно ранее которое трогать не надо).

Подскажите куда копать чтобы это реализовать, буду очень признателен если получу код реализации данного механизма на golang (или на с++ который я потом перепишу, также на golang).

Comment: Можно сделать это используя `Core Audio API` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/core-audio-apis-in-windows-vista), но там всё через COM-интерфейсы. В golang есть поддержка COM?

Comment: не знаю точно, должно быть. на крайняк загуглю с++ код и запихну его в golang. благо так можно.